# How to define a html subtemplate inside a PlayFramework view?

Tags: templates, playframework

From a master html template I'm calling `#{doLayout}` which renders my view html. I'd like to call a custom html template as well such as `#{happyHeader}` which I'd like to define inside my view html file. Something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    #{happyHeader}
    <hr/>
    #{doLayout}
  </body>
</html>
```

And in my `index.html` have something like this:

```
<p>My happy doLayout main content here</p>
#{define happyHeader}
  <h1>Nice header</h1>
#{/}
```

I've looked around StackOverflow and couldn't find a similar question, and neither do the custom template solutions in the Play Framework docs seem to cover this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do this with `#{set}` and `#{get}`.

You set the value in your `index.html` like this:

```
#{set 'happyHeader'}
  <h1>Nice header</h1>
#{/set}
```

And you get it in your `main.html` like this:

```
#{get 'happyHeader' /}
```